# how do I programmatically check git diff --stat to make sure line amount is < x?

Tags: bash, git

I would like to run a script that does `git diff --stat ${{branch compared}}` and parse the output so that I can see that lines in a certain file path didn't exceed x.

My biggest problem is how git formats the output of the command.

I've had a lot of trouble parsing this

```
 .gitignore                                         |  11 +-
 BUGS                                               |   1 +
 Makefile                                           | 907 ++++++++-------------
 README.md                                          |  55 +-
```

Comment: Never use a human-readable format when a machine-readable one is available.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `git diff --numstat` instead? This flag will produce a 3-column table. From the doc:

> Similar to --stat, but shows number of added and deleted lines in decimal notation and pathname without abbreviation, to make it more machine friendly. For binary files, outputs two - instead of saying 0 0.

## Update

take a look at an example output:

```sh
$ git diff --numstat                                                                                                                     [9:09:24]
1734    1   README.md
2       0   requirements.txt
```

We can write a short `awk` script to display those files whose lines changes exceed a threshold (say 1000 lines):

```sh
git diff --numstat | awk '$1 > 1000 || $2 > 1000'
```

This script says *give me those files whos lines added ($1) or lines deleted ($2) are greater than 1000.* The output:

```
1734    1   README.md
```

Comment: that's very helpful! Thank you. My problem is more that when i run 

```
while read $(git diff --numstat master); do
{{work}}
end
```
it hangs on me

I've tried variations like 
```
while read arr; do
```
but i get the same issue

Comment: That is a wholly different issue of reading input into a loop, accomplished by something like `git diff --numstat | while read line; do echo "foo: $line"; done` You should rephrase your question around demonstrable issues, including your code, expectations, and actual output. Otherwise we have to guess at what you're asking about.